# Confusion over ServicePointManager ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, webclient

I am writing a class that inherits from `System.Net.WebClient`.

The `ServiceCertificateValidationCallback` is firing and `(errors == SslPolicyErrors.None)` returns `true`.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
               delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
               System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
               {
                  isTrusted = (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None);
               };
```

Which object or process invokes that callback? And since it *is* being invoked, do I understand correctly that `chain.Build()` would be an unnecessary redundant step?

```
        X509Certificate2 rootCert = (X509Certificate2)certificate;
        X509Certificate2 clientCert =store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, 
                                                                     rootCert.thumbprint, false)[0]

        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add((X509Certificate2) certificate);
        if (chain.Build(clientCert))
        {
            // trusted chain
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which object or process invokes that callback?

In .NET Framework it roughly goes:

- `WebClient` creates an `HttpWebRequest`
- `HttpWebRequest` calls `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri)`
- Resulting `ServicePoint` instance creates connection and registers `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` as a post-handshake hook on any enclosing TLS tunnel.

This is a gross oversimplification, but those are the key public members involved.

> do I understand correctly that `chain.Build()` would be an unnecessary redundant step?

Unless you have a *specific need* to inspect the certificate chain as part of your custom validation routine, yes, it would be redundant.

The OS/platform has already completed the handshake and given its verdict, the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is simply a last chance for you as a user to either discard the connection or go ahead with the web request, based on what was actually negotiated.

Comment: Thanks very much for this clarity: 'The OS/platform has already completed the handshake and given its verdict...'